# Is there terminate event in fluent builder API?

Tags: camunda

I'm modelling a process in code using Fluent Builder API (https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.12/user-guide/model-api/bpmn-model-api/fluent-builder-api/) and I want to insert a terminating event (not end event). I cannot manage to find it (in code or in documentation) does it exist? How do I model it?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not directly supported by the fluent model API. But it can be achieved by modifying the eventDefinition:

```
// plain simple generated bpmn
BpmnModelInstance bpmn = Bpmn.createExecutableProcess()
  .startEvent()
  .serviceTask()
  .endEvent().done();

// find the end event instance in the model (might require filtering by id if more than one)
EndEvent endEvent = bpmn.getModelElementsByType(EndEvent.class).stream().findFirst().get();

// create an EventDefinition for terminate
TerminateEventDefinition terminateEventDefinition = bpmn.newInstance(TerminateEventDefinition.class);

// add that event definition to the endEvent instance 
endEvent.getEventDefinitions().add(terminateEventDefinition);
```

Comment: That workaround has seemed to work. It would be great though to have it directly in the API.
Thank you Jan!

Comment: I would not call it a workaround.  It‘s official api, just not as convenient as the fluent builder.   Maybe you could file a feature request.